# Wordpress - Portfolio - Change number of items in a row

Tags: css

I am using the [Pure theme](http://gt3themes.com/wordpress/pure-free-portfolio-wordpress-theme/). Instead of having five (5) items per row in the portfolio, I want to have four (4).

How could I customize the theme's CSS? To build the page, I am using the portfolio module of the [GT3 Page Builder](http://gt3themes.com/wordpress-gt3-page-builder/).The CSS is below:

```
/* Portfolio */

.optionset {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.optionset li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.optionset li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.optionset li:before {
    display: none !important;
}

.optionset li a {
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.optionset li a:hover, .optionset li.selected a {
    color: #bfbfbf;
}

.portfolio_item {
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.portfolio_item .innerpadding {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.portwrap {
    margin-left: -50px;
}

.portfolio_block {
    margin-top: 68px;
}

.isotope_preloader {
    /*opacity: 0;*/
    min-height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: We don't promote a "do-this-for-me" service, since this a Q&A community. What have you tried to achieve this? Also, may you'll need to provide more details for us to better understand your scenario.

Comment: I would not ask if I had not tried. I just cannot find where this function is located in the css

Comment: May you provide your code?

Comment: Added what seemed to me the relevant section of the code in my question

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you change this line of code it will make 4 portfolio items in a row.

change this :

```
.portfolio_item { width: 20%; margin-bottom: 40px; }
```

to this :

```
.portfolio_item { width: 25%; margin-bottom: 40px; }
```

divide 100 to no of columns you  want. e.g 100/4 = 25 so 25% for 4 items in a row and 100/5 = 20 which is already set to 20%.

Comment: if css does not work then add `!important` after 25% e.g  `width: 25% !important;` clear cache and refresh the page. or click on portfolio filter to see the changes.